# Using SystemCommandTasklet to split file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, flat-file, spring-batch-tasklet

I want to run System Commands via SystemCommandTasklet.Itried this with the sample code below but I get an error.

I think this because of command parameter,But I could not fix it.

I would be very glad if it will help.

Reference Examples ;

- [Using SystemCommandTasklet for split the large flat file into small files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725053/using-systemcommandtasklet-for-split-the-large-flat-file-into-small-files)
- [Trying to split files using SystemCommandTasklet - Execution of system command did not finish within the timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500034/trying-to-split-files-using-systemcommandtasklet-execution-of-system-command-d)

Error Detail ;

> "CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Code Sample ;

```
 @Bean
@StepScope
public SystemCommandTasklet fileSplitterSystemCommandTasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['file']}") File file) throws Exception {

    final String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String outputDirectory = file.getPath().substring(0, file.getPath().lastIndexOf(fileSeparator)) + fileSeparator + "out" + fileSeparator;

    File output = new File(outputDirectory);

    if (!output.exists()) {
        output.mkdir();
    }

    final String command = String.format("split -a 5 -l 10000 %s %s",file.getName(),outputDirectory);

    var fileSplitterTasklet = new SystemCommandTasklet();
    fileSplitterTasklet.setCommand(command);
    fileSplitterTasklet.setTimeout(60000L);
    fileSplitterTasklet.setWorkingDirectory(outputDirectory);
    fileSplitterTasklet.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    fileSplitterTasklet.setSystemProcessExitCodeMapper(touchCodeMapper());
    fileSplitterTasklet.afterPropertiesSet();
    fileSplitterTasklet.setInterruptOnCancel(true);
    fileSplitterTasklet.setEnvironmentParams(new String[]{
            "JAVA_HOME=/java",
            "BATCH_HOME=/Users/batch"});
    return fileSplitterTasklet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `file.getAbsolutePath()` instead of `file.getPath()`.

Also, you are using `file.getName()` in the command:

```
final String command = String.format("split -a 5 -l 10000 %s %s",file.getName(),outputDirectory);
```

You should pass the absolute path of the file or make sure to set
the working directory correctly so that the `split` command is executed
in the same directory as the file.

Comment: First off all thank you so much for your help #Ma @Mahmoud Ben Hassine.I tried but it didn't work.file.getAbsolutePath() and file.getPath() return same value.

Comment: Your issue `The system cannot find the file specified` means the file cannot be found. Make sure file path is correct regarding the working directory: `fileSplitterTasklet.setWorkingDirectory(outputDirectory);`

Comment: Directory and file is correct and exists.If I try with not exists file and directory,the error message is  "directory path must exists".

Comment: You are using `file.getName()` in the command, you need to make sure the final `split` command is correct (the command is executed in the correct directory, the file path is correct, etc). Try to debug to see the final command and see if it's correct.

Comment: The split command is correct.I have checked command by a command executer,and  it is executed successfully.Do you have any code example which executed successfully?