# Using SystemCommandTasklet to split a large file in Windows

Tags: java, spring-batch, cloud-foundry

I am trying to split a large flat file into multiple files using SystemCommandTasklet in Spring Batch. I am retrieving the large file from scality and storing it in the temp directory.

I'm getting the below error:
Cannot run program "split" (in directory "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

This is a duplicate of the question [Using SystemCommandTasklet to split file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753608/using-systemcommandtasklet-to-split-file). But I'm still unable to implement this.

Split works fine in Unix/Linux.

I'm using a windows machine, so does split using SystemCommandTasklet work in windows machine?

Comment: It looks like you have some good debug statements in that code, can you please provide the output for all of it?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMinella,
Split works in PCF as it is Unix/Linux OS. Below are the logs of PCF. I've split a file with 250 rows into three files with 100 and 50 rows.

 split -a 5 -l 100 /tmp/ERR_File.pgp /tmp/out/


Container became healthy



 /tmp/out/aaaaa
 100


 /tmp/out/aaaab
 100


 /tmp/out/aaaac
 50

 Job: [SimpleJob: [name=Job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 1s217ms

Comment: The same code is not working in my windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Spring Batch issue. It is because the `split` command is not available on windows. That's why it works on unix/linux but not on MS windows.

You need to find an equivalent command on windows and pass it to your `SystemCommandTasklet`. Otherwise you have to write some portable code to split a file (in Java for instance) that would work on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look to find an equivalent command in Windows.